# Parsing Scenes From A Screenplay

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Hi I'm trying to parse out scenes from a screenplay. I recently posted about dialogue and the regex pro @Wiktor Stribiżew helped me out. I was able to use this pattern to almost capture the scenes perfectly however Im looking for a little more help.

So you'll see I've captured two groups. group 1 for the EXT and INT which indicate a new scene and group 2 for the content of the scene. However, I'm looking to add BURNETT HOUSE - DAY to group 1. Basically adding context to the scene. This almost does it `([A-Z]+\b.)` but Im not sure how to merge it and it's sloppy and catches some single capital letters.

```
7    INT. COLONY HOTEL - STAIRWELL - NIGHT                       7
     Lowrey and Burnett clip on their shields and unholster
     their guns. The posing is over. This is business.


A8   INT. COLONY HOTEL - SUITE 202 - NIGHT                       A8
     On the table are two briefcases. Each opened. One
     containing cocaine. The other, cash. A pistol next
     to each.
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there, but in some cases there is a double space between the scene and the scene content and the match misses it. Should I edit the post to reflect this?

301   EXT. BURNETT HOUSE - DAY \n\n scene content \n\n 302   INT. BURNETT HOUSE - DAY

Comment: Add `+` after `\n` then, images do not help, please add text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b((?:INT|EXT)\..*\S)[^\S\n]+[a-zA-Z]*\d+\n(?s:(.+?)(?=\b(?:EXT|INT)\.|\Z))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o3wOOV/4).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `((?:INT|EXT)\..*\S)` - Group 1: `INT` or `EXT`, then a `.`, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then a non-whitespace char
- `[^\S\n]+` - one or more whitespaces other than a newline char
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more ASCII letters
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\n` - a newline
- `(?s:` - start of an innline modifier group where `.` matches any char:

  - `(.+?)` - Group 2: one or more chars as many as possible
  - `(?=\b(?:EXT|INT)\.|\Z)` - up to the leftmost `EXT` or `INT` followed with a dot, or till the end of string
- `)` - end of the group.

Comment: Im actually not sure why its not capturing that 3rd paragraph but thanks I'll play around with this pattern!

Comment: @DigitalMoniker If you add text to the question, I cold help, too.

Comment: added a chunk there...I see issues with (CONTINUED) breaking the parse too but not sure why some INT. / EXT. arent captured

Comment: Added a second paste there which has both issues I listed above...sorry to keep changing it.

Comment: Try `\b((?:INT|EXT)\..*\S)[^\S\n]+\d+\n+(.+(?:\n.+)*)`, see https://regex101.com/r/o3wOOV/3

Comment: Still failing at certain points I think maybe its to do with some pages starting with a number 7...while other starts with A7. Ill edit the post to paste one more location where it fails.

Comment: I added a fresh text where it captures the first chunk but fails on the second chunk

Comment: @DigitalMoniker Try matching from INT/EXT till next INT/EXT with `\b((?:INT|EXT)\..*\S)[^\S\n]+[a-zA-Z]*\d+\n(?s:(.+?)(?=\b(?:EXT|INT)\.|\Z))`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o3wOOV/4).

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much. I'm going to buy you some coffee for that now

Comment: Do you want to edit the OA and Ill accept it?

Comment: @DigitalMoniker I have edited the answer, it is difficult to type on a small DELL Inspiron duo laptop, it is also very slow itself.

Comment: Accepted, thanks again @Wiktor Stribiżew.